# In still in the sentence

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context

The river shrinks and black crows gorge on bright mangoes in still, dustgreen trees.

Comment: It's "still (dustgreen) trees".  The mangoes are in the trees.

Comment: Hi user361849. The trees are still. It means they are not moving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author uses "...*in still*..." to describe the "...*the (dustgreen) trees.*"

Since the author is describing the trees, *in still* is an adjective.

Using the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/still), *still* is defined as:

> staying in the same position; not moving:

So the author is describing "...*the (dustgreen) trees*"  to be not moving.